# Is there a version of Poincare recurrence theorem on attracting set?

Tags: dynamical-systems, classical-mechanics, ergodic-theory

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.04358), on the left-side on page 2, it has a statement of poincare recurrence theorem, which I quoted here:

*Statement 1: Our algorithm relies
on the Poincaré recurrence theorem, which states that a trajectory on an attracting set will sooner or later visit the same regions of the state space.*

I found it is difficult to find which version of poincare recurrence theorem match this statement. The poincare recurrence theorem stated in many textbooks in ergodic theory and dynamical system is about volume preserving system, and the recurrence property applies to any bounded region in the phase space. I quote the definition from the book Mathematical methods of classical mechanics from V.I. Arnold here:

*Statement 2: Let $g$ be a volume-preserving continuous one to one mapping which maps a bounded region $D$ of euclidean space onto itself: $gD=D$. Then in any neighborhood $U$ of any point of $D$ there is a point $x\in U$ which returns to $U$, i.e. $g^nx\in U$ for some $n>0$.*

Could someone help to clarify what the first statement of poincare recurrence is about? maybe there exists a version of the theorem that specialized for attracting set?

Answer (score 1):

That version of the Poincaré recurrence theorem that you cite is just one special case of a much more general theorem.

The Wikipedia page for [Poincaré recurrence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_recurrence_theorem) seems to have a good statement of [the general theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_recurrence_theorem#Formal_statement). Here is a brief description.

In your setting $g$ restricts to an area preserving self-map $g : D \to D$. So you can generalize $D$ to any set $\Sigma$ equipped with a $\sigma$-algebra and a finite measure $\mu$. And then you can generalize $g : D \to D$ to any measure preserving transformation $f : \Sigma \to \Sigma$ meaning that for any measurable subset $A \subset \Sigma$ its inverse image $f^{-1}(A)$ is measurable and $\mu(f^{-1}(A)) = \mu(A)$. The conclusion of the theorem is that the subset
$$\{x \in A \mid \exists n \ge 1, f^n(x) \in A\}
$$
has full measure $\mu(A)$ (for any measurable $A \subset \Sigma$).

Notice that one-to-one is not even mentioned in this more generalized version. In the special case that $f$ is one-to-one, the measure preserving requirement $\mu(f^{-1}(A))=\mu(A)$ is equivalent to $\mu(f(B))=\mu(B)$ (identifying $B$ with $f^{-1}(A)$).

Notice also that continuity is not mentioned. All that is important is that continuity$+$area preserving implies that the transformation is measure preserving.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I still have the confusion about: how this general version related to the first statement?

Comment: Ah, I may have misunderstood. Is there some other version of Poincaré recurrence that you are interested in? If so, you should include it in your post (as suggested in our guidelines for [formatting and writing](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992)).

Comment: The brief statement of your post is not quite precise enough to know what you are referring to; I can only guess that this is about an area preserving flow of some kind, perhaps generated by some differential equation.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! Since I am trying to understand the principle behind the algorithm proposed in the paper, and the principle (the first statement in my post) stated in the paper is quite intuitive rather than mathematical. It does not match any version of poincare recurrence theorem.. It looks like taking region $D$ as the basin of attraction. Since my knowledge in dynamical system is quite limited, I post the question here to see how other experienced people would see about the statement 1

Comment: If my guess is right (in my previous comment), your statement will just follow from the one in my answer by using the time 1 map of the flow. But, without knowing exactly what kind of dynamical system that brief quote is referring to, it's hard to say. One really does need some version of "measure preserving" or else Poincaré recurrence can fail.

Comment: Yes, if I understand correctly, first we need a volume-preserving system, then we can say something about recurrence. Or, we need an area that is volume-preserving, then we can say something about recurrence on that area. Moreover, what would make the first statement right is any basin of attraction has volume-preserving property, which I am not sure whether this is true.

Comment: Well, there's a few last things to be said. First, there are some broad contexts in which any **measurable** transformation has an invariant **measure**. But also, since that quote you made is so out-of-context, the best I can recommend is that in order to understand what *those authors* mean by the Poincare recurrence theorem, you should trace through the references of the paper, and/or look at how the paper actually applies the theorem.

Comment: Got it, Thanks a lot!!